# I have a white screen when I run the google maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I set up the google api and run the app on a samsung device with google play services but nothing happened I had a withe screen withthe google logo on the buttom even if I had an internet connexion and activated the google location

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.myapplication" >
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string 
resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign 
 the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the 
release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in 
src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.myapplication.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[Api console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPqLl.png).
[the MapsActivity code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgSr9.png)

Comment: Add code of `MapsActivity`.

Comment: Try to zoom out;)

Comment: Check logs there might be possibility that your configuration or api key is incorrect. Add screenshot for visitors that would also be helpful.

Comment: I added code for the maps activity

Comment: check your logcat and generate your Maps API key

Answer (score 0):

Make sure API key is not restricted for Android Apps, By default it is restricted

you can enable it from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup)

Comment: you mean I need to set the application restriction to none

Comment: or I need to set api restriction to maps sdk for android

Comment: set application restriction to none